# Can i integrate a PayPal button into my HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I'm having some issues adding a PayPal button to my HTML. Not sure if its possible, but what I want it to take the price output generated by the JavaScript when pressed by the PayPal "Buy Now" button and allow them to buy the product. if anyone could tell me with this is feasible it would be greatly appreciated.

My code so far:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- boost script by thelamp  -->
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script>
        var costs = [ 10,10,10,10,10,
                      15,15,15,15,15,
                      20,20,20,20,20,
                      25,25,25,25,25,
                      30,30,30,30,30];

        function calc() {
            var fromValue = document.getElementById("from").selectedIndex;

            var toValue = document.getElementById("to").selectedIndex;

            if (fromValue < toValue) {
                var price = 0;

                for (i = fromValue; i < toValue; i++) {
                    price += costs[i];
                }

                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = 'Target Rank needs to be higher than the your Rank.';
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>


    From:
        <select id="from" onchange="calc()">
            <option>Silver 1</option>
            <option>Silver 2</option>
            <option>Silver 3</option>
            <option>Silver 4</option>
            <option>Silver Elite</option>
            <option>Silver Elite Master</option>
            <option>Gold Nova 1</option>
            <option>Gold Nova 2</option>
            <option>Gold Nova 3</option>
            <option>Gold Nova Master</option>
            <option>Master Guardian 1</option>
            <option>Master Guardian 2</option>
            <option>Master Guardian Elite</option>
            <option>Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
            <option>Legendary Eagle</option>
            <option>Legendary Eagle Master</option>
            <option>Supreme Master First Class</option>
            <option>Global Elite</option>
        </select>

        To:
        <select id="to" onchange="calc()">
            <option>Silver 1</option>
            <option>Silver 2</option>
            <option>Silver 3</option>
            <option>Silver 4</option>
            <option>Silver Elite</option>
            <option>Silver Elite Master</option>
            <option>Gold Nova 1</option>
            <option>Gold Nova 2</option>
            <option>Gold Nova 3</option>
            <option>Gold Nova Master</option>
            <option>Master Guardian 1</option>
            <option>Master Guardian 2</option>
            <option>Master Guardian Elite</option>
            <option>Distinguished Master Guardian</option>
            <option>Legendary Eagle</option>
            <option>Legendary Eagle Master</option>
            <option>Supreme Master First Class</option>
            <option>Global Elite</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>

        Price:
        <div id="price">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible and totally feasible. I don't see a button in your markup, however.

Comment: Yeah there isn't one as of that markup. I've been having issues adding it because when I press "Buy Now" my price listed on the page before would show (Got $0.00)

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine for me. Could you point out what's wrong? [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/eztuwny9/) is the Fiddle.

Comment: @peter Yes that does work, but it has to be able to redirect to PayPal and charge them whatever rank they chose from the drop down.

Comment: If that's working for you now, [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/web/) might be a good starting point for how to take it from here.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, the JavaScript buttons require a set amount, but what I need is the set amount to change based on what the user selects.

Comment: No, the button will take whatever amount your div with id `price` is displaying. And the amount displayed there is in accordance with user's selected options, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. Would there be a way to instead use a PayPal button? (Still taking the div as the price)

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/eztuwny9/1/) what you are after?

Comment: Somewhat. What I'm really looking for is for me to take whatever number outputted when pressing 'Buy Now' and have to user re-directed to PayPal where they would pay that amount to me. I can give you a website that already does this method if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="oceLoL">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">

<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value= "1"> 

<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_SM.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynow_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>

</body>
```

Hi, following up on the above question, how would you pull the user selections into the paypal details?

Regarding the below coding:

'Item name' value should be based off what the user has selected, i.e. 'silver 1 to gold nova 1'
'amount value' should be be the same case and be based on what the user's selections.